# Best translation for “software-development manager”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, difference, single-word-request

I’m interested in learning the job title for a person who has HR responsibility for a group of developers (*software-development manager* in English).

I’ve been looking at a few sites, and I’m trying to understand the differences between *Entwicklungsleiter, Entwicklungsmanager,* and *Entwicklungschef.* Are these three terms interchangeable, or are there subtle differences between them?

For example, it seems that *Entwicklungsleiter* is often translated as *director,* a head of a department. In English, a director often has a group of managers reporting to him or her, so that might not be the best term.

Comment: Job titles seem to vary widely between companies. They are cheap, so some companies may call her "HR specialist" if the secretary also hands out pay checks. I've worked for a company where everybody was "senior", "principal", "head" or whatnot. We even had a "deputy quality manager". Some folks call themselves the CEO if they run a one-man company and are basically just entrepreneurs.

Comment: Of course, I'm aware there are degenerate cases.

Comment: It will be difficult to find a definitive answer here. Quite often, companies do not have a separate title for the head of a developement department, but name all their department heads 'Abteilungsleiter', independent of the function of the department they manage. All the options you mentioned *may* be appropriate, but it depends a lot on the company. Are you trying to translate a job description/title for a specific position or do you need a term for addressing persons in such positions in general (e.g. in marketing material of some kind)?

Comment: I speak some German. I'm working for a company with a presence in Germany and would like to know how to describe my position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer but I am a software developer in Germany so here comes my experience:

I have heard Entwicklungsleiter and Entwicklungsmanager but not Entwicklungschef.

Softeareentwicklungsleiter seems too long even for Germans but I've seen *Leiter Softwareentwicklung* or A*bteilungsleiter Softwareentwicklung* used in several companies. The *Leiter Softwareentwicklung* usually managed multiple teams and had the HR responsibilities of hiring/firing, disciplinary measures, salary negotiations and performance reviews.

The day-to-day management of assigning tasks, tracking progress, motivating the team and making decisions the developers can't or don't want to make alone, is usually done by someone called *Projektleiter*, *technischer Projektleiter*, *Software Projektleiter*, or *Teamleiter Softwareentwicklung* (sometimes + topic the team works on).

What do you need the title for? If it's a CV, just put whatever you like and explain in a sentence or two what exactly you did at that job.

Comment: Thank you for explaining some of the nuances between those works.